# Setting up dev enviroment with git but not loading bootstrap and font awesome

Tags: git, sass, gulp

So I was trying to set up my dev enviroment because I'm following guy on the tutorial, he's using older version of gulp which works with older version of Node.js, but newer version doesn't... I'm currently running gulp v4 and node is the latest version and it just don't want to cooperate... Using git I want to install bootstrap and fontawesome since I already installed SASS and it's working, but I haven't found code to put for bootstrap and fontawesome in gulpfile.js... Here is how my code is looking right now, SASS is working and site updates itself, but I don't know how to export bootstrap and fontawesome since in gulp 4 everything has changed...

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const sass = require('gulp-sass');
const browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();

//compile scss into css
function style() {
    return gulp.src('src/scss/**/*.scss')
        .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('src/css'))
        .pipe(browserSync.stream());
}

function watch() {
    browserSync.init({
        server: {
            baseDir: "./src",
            index: "/index.html"
        }
    });
    gulp.watch('src/scss/**/*.scss', style)
    gulp.watch('./*.html').on('change', browserSync.reload);
    gulp.watch('./js/**/*.js').on('change', browserSync.reload);
}

exports.style = style;
exports.watch = watch;
```

Comment: this is code from the course if anyone is looking for it... https://github.com/bradtraversy/bs4starter/blob/master/gulpfile.js

Comment: From the pop-up info on tag:git: *Also, do not use this tag for general programming questions that happen to involve a Git repository.*